# Process blade templates inside strings

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-blade, braces

I have a scenario, where the user can set a text template and use placeholders in braces, that should be replaced dynamicly.

For example the user input could be strings like:

```
$userinput = '<p> Hello {{$name}} <\p>';
$userinput = '<p> Hi {{$name}} <\p>';
```

I want to display this input with the expanded placeholders in a view `message.blade.php`

```
@section('content')
    {!! $userinput !!}
@stop
```

The HTML gets rendered correctly, but but of course {{$name}} isnt substituted with 'Alice'.

```
view('message')->with([
            'userinput' => $userinput,
            'name' => 'Alice',]);
```

Is there a simple way to process the inner placeholder as well? Can i interpret the blade file a second time?

PS: I am aware, that unescaped userinputs are evil.

Comment: have you tried dd()?? did you checked that you receive any value for name?? also have you tried using {{$var}} instead {!!$var!!}

Comment: `$userinput = '<p> Hello '.$name.' </p>';` would work wouldn't it? If you're defining the `$userinput` in a `Controller`, you shouldn't need to use `blade` shorthands.

Comment: If you are inside of a <?php block you shouldnt be using blade syntax anyway.

Comment: Giving the user capability to execute arbitrary code (even if it's via blade) seems like a bad idea, if you must, you can do `\Blade::compileString($userinput)`.

Comment: You can use this package to render string templates with blade: https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler

Comment: Yes, all variables are set correctly. I can't use {{$var}} because i need the html tags untouched. 
@TimLewis Doing it in php would be my second approach, i hoped there would be a simple workarround using the blade tags.

Comment: "I am aware, that unescaped userinputs are evil" I don't believe you. This is very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You could change:
`$userinput = '<p> Hello {{$name}} <\p>';` 
for `$userinput = '<p> Hello {!! $name !!} <\p>';` 
That will scape the sequence before the render.